# how to show original size of an image on tapping on gridView tile

Tags: image, flutter, dart, gridview

1. gridview has tile with image : cachedNetworkImage(widget.post.mediaUrl >> this code works fine
2. on tapping the tile, I want to show original size or bigger image of a tile as images are arranged in gridview and are small.
3. to test I added onTap() and returning a scaffold with test image but it is doing nothing on tap ( except printing line 19) .

questions :

1. what do I need to show the actual post image ?
2. not sure why scaffold is not returned on tap ?

```
        class _PostTileState extends State<PostTile> {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return GestureDetector(
              child: cachedNetworkImage(widget.post.mediaUrl),
              onTap: () {
                print("line19");
                return Scaffold(
                    body: GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Hero(
                      tag: 'imageHero',
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ));
              },
            );
          }
```

Comment: Go for a dialog: https://medium.com/@nils.backe/flutter-alert-dialogs-9b0bb9b01d28

Comment: hi @racr0x, added alert dialog, instead of Scaffold and still nothing,  below posted solution by chunhunghan worked, so going with that one, will use alert box somewhere else, thanks for the link !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In you case, you can use Full Screen Dialog 
code snippet

```
return GestureDetector(
      child: Image.network(widget.mediaUrl),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                fullscreenDialog: true,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    body: GestureDetector(
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Hero(
                          tag: 'imageHero',
                          child: Image.network(
                            widget.mediaUrl,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }));
      },
    );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GridView(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2, //横轴三个子widget
              childAspectRatio: 1.0 //宽高比为1时，子widget
              ),
          children: <Widget>[
            PostTile('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
            PostTile('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
            PostTile('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
            PostTile('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PostTile extends StatefulWidget {
  String mediaUrl;
  PostTile(this.mediaUrl);

  @override
  _PostTileState createState() => _PostTileState();
}

class _PostTileState extends State<PostTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Image.network(widget.mediaUrl),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                fullscreenDialog: true,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    body: GestureDetector(
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Hero(
                          tag: 'imageHero',
                          child: Image.network(
                            widget.mediaUrl,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chunhunhan : worked like a charm! - excellent

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.